# Why isn't python-exposed boost::gregorian::date available everywhere?

Tags: python-3.x, boost, boost-python, typeconverter

I exposed boost::gregorian::date with the following:

```
date_from_python_date{};
to_python_converter<date, date_to_python_date, true>{};
```

where **date_to_python_date** is a struct with the right convert function: it converts it to a python datetime.date.
Some c++ functions return date and calling them from python works.

At a later stage, I have a c++ class

```
class F {
/// ....
public:
    boost::gregorian::date start;
};
```

which I register with:

```
class_<F, F*, bases<B>>("F")
  .def_readwrite("start", &F::start, "FTD")
;
```

I do this after having python-registered date.
I then obtain an instance f of the F wrapper. But then, when I print

```
f.start
```

The error is:

```
No Python class registered for C++ class boost::gregorian::date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the return policy used by `def_readonly()` and `def_readwrite()` will default to using [`return_internal_reference`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_internal_reference.html#return_internal_reference-spec) for user-defined class types (see [`make_getter()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/data_members.html#make_getter-spec)).  This return policy will suppress the use of custom converters.  To resolve this, replace `def_readonly()` and `def_readwrite()` with `add_property()`, providing a [`boost::python::return_value_policy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_value_policy.html#return_value_policy-spec) with a type of [`boost::python::return_by_value`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_by_value.html#return_by_value-spec).

Change:

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
python::class_<F, F*, python::bases<B>>("F")
  .def_readwrite("start", &F::start, "FTD")
;
```

to:

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
python::class_<F, F*, python::bases<B>>("F")
  .add_property("start",
    python::make_getter(
      &F::start, python::return_value_policy<python::return_by_value>()),
    python::make_setter(
      &F::start, python::return_value_policy<python::return_by_value>()),
    "FTD")
  ;
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0c42391030a6682) this difference:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// Mocks...
// Mockup user defined type.
class spam {};
struct egg
{
  spam spam;
};

// Mockup convert that converts spam into 'hello world' strings.
struct spam_converter
{
  static PyObject* convert(const spam&)
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::str result("hello world");
    return python::incref(result.ptr());
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

   // Enable spam to string converter.
  python::to_python_converter<spam, spam_converter>();

  // Expose egg.
  python::class_<egg>("Egg")
     // Expose egg::spam as spam1, access will fail to find converter.
    .def_readonly("spam1", &egg::spam)
    // Expose egg::spam as spam2, automatic conveter will be found.
    .add_property("spam2", 
      python::make_getter(
        &egg::spam, python::return_value_policy<python::return_by_value>()))
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> egg = example.Egg()
>>> try:
...     spam = egg.spam1 # expect to throw
...     assert(False)
... except TypeError:
...     assert(True)
...
>>> spam = egg.spam2
>>> assert(spam == "hello world")
```

Note that although the same `egg::spam` data-member instance was being exposed as `Egg.spam1` and `Egg.spam2`, the manner in which the data-member was being exposed affected whether or not the automatic converter was found during dispatch.

Comment: I figured this by myself last night just as I was about o to give it all up:-)
short night